# Math.Pow in C# not return correct value

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I want to use C# to demonstrate RSA cryptography. I pick p=17 and q=11. So I get N=187 and e=7 and d=23.

When I pick character X (88 in decimal in ASCII) and encrypt it:

```
double enCrypt = Math.Pow(88, 7) % 187;
```

and it return value `enCrypt =11`

Then, I want to decrypt it, so I calculate:

```
double deCrypt = Math.Pow(11, 23) % 187;
```

but it's not return to the original value 88 but `deCrypt=149`!

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) if you want to do the mod and pow steps separately. (If you want to use a fixed-size integer type, you need to implement [modpow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) yourself, since the only place it’s built into .NET is `BigInteger`.) `double` can only store integers unambiguously up to 2^53−1, and 11^23 is larger.

Comment: OMG. Thanks so muchhhh!